# Moving elements?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to do something like [**here**](http://www.joeys.de/) the moving ingredients of pizza in jquery for example or somehow?

Comment: Don't ask or expect people to follow random links from your question, *explain* what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You should explain your question clearly (-1). Though you can do something like this:

```
#tomato{ position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;}
$("#tomato").animate({ left: "+=20" }, 5000);
```

You can also do it with CSS3:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform http://jsfiddle.net/nSa9s/2/